# show image in percentage sized canvas HTML5/JS/ASP.NET MVC/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, html, canvas

I have to "fix" a ASP.NET MVC 5 Website. Gridlayout is done with bootstrap.
The Problem is, there is a Canvas, that should fill a "50% width" div. 
When I set the width of the Canvas to 100% that works great.
In the canvas i want to show an Image I got from an Controller. To show it in the right resolution i need to set the height of the Canvas, but first I need to know how many Pixels I got in X-Dimension, to scale the image. 
Is there any nice way to do so? I tried

```
parentDiv.innerWidth()
canvas.clientWidth
canvas.style.width
parentDiv.clientWidth
```

Most of them returned zero.

It needs to be an canvas, where I show the image, because I want to draw something in the image.

Any idea?

Thanks

EDIT:

Is there a "good" way to show an image in a canvas, that is sized in percent?

Comment: `HTMLElement.clientWidth` is a property, not a function. Strange you got 0 and not an error. Ps beware of capitalization.

Comment: Sorry, just wrote this question this Morning, yeah, it was `parentDiv.clientWidth`

Comment: So your problem is solved? Then you can delete it.

Comment: nope, it's not solved,
`parentDiv.innerWidth()` returns `0`
`canvas.clientWidth` returns `" "`
`parentDiv.clientWidth` returns `" "`

Comment: When are you calling the function that reads the parent dimensions in javascript? I always have trouble doing element layout in javascript unless I trigger the layout function from window.onresize = function() {

Comment: does not work either :/